# Exponential Shorthand for Integers

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, exponential, static-cast

So my understanding is that this: `1e3` Equates to `1000.0`.

My question is, is there a similar shorthand for integers? I realize that I can do: `static_cast<int>(1e3)`. Is there anything available to me outside of this?

Comment: Are you okay with creating a UDL? I believe it could be done

Comment: *Is there anything available to me outside of this?* I am guessing you are asking for something that's already built into the language or the standard library.

Comment: Binary is already an exponential shorthand for integers.  Unary would be the long form: X = 1, XX = 2, XXX = 3, etc.

Comment: @stark That's completely irrelevant

Comment: @RSahu Yeah I was hoping for something that was built into the language.

Comment: @Justin Hmmm... I assume that UDL meant User Defined Literals. I hadn't considered that. But looking at [user2079303's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51957160/2642059) I have to say it looks like a strong solution.

Comment: `static_cast<int>(some_double_constant)` can lack precision when the precision of `double` with whole number values is less than the integer width.  Consider `static_cast<int>(some_long_double_constant)`.

Comment: @chux Sure that's another whole problem. I was really just looking for the convenience of that "e" notation. Sounds like user defined literals would be my only hope, which of course would incur all the drawbacks you mention.

Comment: Note: Various ideas mentioned incurred a fixed type via  `static_cast<int>()` or `int operator "" _i()`.  `2.147483648e9` will not become a `long` like `2147483648` does (unless `int` is more than 32 bit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no syntax for scientific notation integer literal in C++.

You could shorten the conversion with a user defined literal:

```
constexpr int operator "" _i(long double d) noexcept {
    return d;
}

int main() {
    auto big = 1e3_i; // is int
}
```

However, this does (at least on GCC that I tested) prevent the compiler from noticing overflow in the initialization so in those cases where possible, prefer the more conventional:

```
int big = 1e30; // compiler should yell at you
```

Comment: That can be `constexpr` right?  There are significant advantages to a "constant integral expression", such as being usable in array bounds, template parameters, etc.

Comment: @BenVoigt as far as I know, yes. It can be `noexcept` too.

Comment: Very interesting - and good use of `long double`.   The function could also detect if the conversion is not _exact_.

Comment: @chux Would you suggest that the function should throw in that case?

Comment: As the use case for your nifty `operator "" _i()` applies to forming an _integer literal_, I'd recommend code should throw on inexact, (also for out of range, NAN).  I'm on the fence about `-0.0`, yet lean toward throwing on that too.  Expect that precules `noexcept`. Hmmm.

Comment: The compiler will yell at you if you mark the variable as `constexpr` for `constexpr int big = 1e30_i;`. Basically, if the `operator""_i()` is evaluated as `constexpr`, you'll get a compilation error because overflow isn't allowed in `constexpr`.

Comment: With C++20 you can use `consteval` instead of `constexpr` in operator definition and compiler will always yell at your on overflow, even when using non-constexpr variables.